# Is it possible to integrate SSO with IIS in Microsoft Reporting Services 2012?

Tags: iis, reporting-services, architecture, ssrs-2012, n-tier-architecture

I have SQL Server 2012 Reporting services and want to integrate SSO functionality. Was thinking about using IIS to do so but then read something that IIS is not part of SSRS anymore. Can we still(in Sql server 2012 Reporting services) work with IIS in SSRS and then enable SSO in IIS?

Comment: It is not part of IIS anymore. I guess you could link from an IIS page to a report. Here is an answer with some links on using SSO with SSRS in general https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e0177da-2332-48ed-b731-d56b63e8c436/how-to-implements-sso-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @JerryRitcey thank you for the answer. i am in search of using IIS with SSRS, not sure if there is any possibility to use them together even thought IIS is not a dependency of SSRS anymore.

Comment: No, SSRS has not been on IIS since SQL Server 2008